# Excel-2013 - Unable to open files from URL

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

Trying to use the following line to open up a file saved online in Excel-2013 and requires logging in to get it.

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=link
```

With link being similar to https://www.stuff.com/file/csv/filetoopen.csv
This works fine for me (tried 2010 and 2013) but when tried on two different laptops (one 2010, the other 2013) Excel says it can't open the file. At first I thought it could be related to the problem discussed here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563
but I found that on the Excel 2013 laptop that it doesn't open any files online, even files that aren't on a server that requires log in which along with me having no problems suggests it is something wrong on the client side, not server. Trust center settings appear to be the same as mine so not seeing a solution there. Has anyone else come across this and have a solution that worked for them?